# webpack devserver build project but not refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I try to create a webpack starter.

I dont know why but when I write changes in my project, webpack devserver build project but not refresh the browser.

This behaviour occur since I have added typescript to my project. I dont't kwow why, can someone help me ?

Here is my repo : https://github.com/jbty/html-starter-typscript-scss-tailwind

Here is my config files:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/assets/ts/app.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'assets/images',
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'assets/fonts',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),
    new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
      minimizerOptions: {
        // Lossless optimization with custom option
        // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
        plugins: [
          ['gifsicle', { interlaced: true }],
          ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
          ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
          [
            'svgo',
            {
              plugins: [
                {
                  removeViewBox: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'src/public' }],
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    writeToDisk: true,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.build.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "dist/**/*spec.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", ".eslintrc.js"]
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/assets/ts/app.ts',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/scss'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[hash].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'assets/images',
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'assets/fonts',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html',
    }),
    new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
      minimizerOptions: {
        // Lossless optimization with custom option
        // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
        plugins: [
          ['gifsicle', { interlaced: true }],
          ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
          ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
          [
            'svgo',
            {
              plugins: [
                {
                  removeViewBox: false,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        ],
      },
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'src/public' }],
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    watchContentBase: true,
    writeToDisk: true,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `target: 'node'` into `target: 'web'` or remove this line, see [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target) for more information.